# Is there a tool to combine two different sides of a asymmetrical bottle design? Previously used rail sweep in Rhino

Tags: modeling, mesh, faces

New to Blender and trying really hard to get myself immersed in it. I've come across something that I can't seem to find an answer for no matter what I google.

Previously I'd use Rhino's command for this, and use a rail sweep to create a mesh between two paths. You select the start path, the end path, and the point of rotation (center). It worked very well in allowing me to create unusual asymmetrical designs in a rotation. I've tried and tried to get something similar to work in Blender but I'm missing something. Please disregard the fact that the highlighted meshes are currently in the same shape, I tried combining them as a last attempt to get Grid Fill to work. No go. Does anyone have any thoughts?

Picture 1 shows a side view of the front profile of my bottle shape.
[image]

Picture 2 shows the profile of the side of my imagined bottle shape.
[image]

Picture 3 is a crudely drawn visualization of what I'm trying to achieve.
[image]

Sweeping the face from one to the other in a seamless and accurate manner. I appreciate anyone's time that can give me some help. Thank you!

Comment: Hello, do you have the same numbef of vertices in both profiles ?

Comment: I haven't counted them out, but I did just read that they need to be the same for a Grid Fill command, is that correct? I'll try counting them and correcting them if I don't. Should this work if they were the same? I'm just curious if my train of thought is correct.

Comment: If you convert them to curves, you can use the loft option in the animation nodes. It's a bit complicated, but googleing animation nodes loft might help you.

Comment: Thanks for the info Frederik. I just watched a video on it and you're right, this might work better. Especially if I can edit the dimensions of the curves before I loft them together. I'll have to give this a try. I'll still have to go back and tighten things up, but if it gets me 90% there quickly than I'll be happy.

Comment: @FrederikSteinmetz for what it's worth, I just used the lofting method that you brought up, and although it requires a proper set up in t he beginning, it achieves a much faster and cleaner solution. I simply placed the circles down in one view (x for example), switched to Y axis view and adjusted the circles to make sure they met the smaller profile, then used the loop loft and it worked perfectly. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2):

you can use the *Bridge Edge Loops* function. As Gorgious says, make sure that you have the same number of vertices, switch to *Edge Selection*, select all, press right click > *Bridge Edge Loop*s, and in the *Operator* box set the *Number of Cuts* and the *Smoothness* values:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Moonboots, I just tried this out with a slightly altered version of the files I'd posted and it does what I was hoping! I'm not sure how it will work with the top and bottom of the bottle, maybe I'll try making them separately and adding them once I have the weird asymmetrical part done. I'll have to play around with that, but this is already much further along than I was getting before. I appreciate the help!

Comment: it may help for some parts, and for some others you can rework the topology manually